# Python: How to get double backslash from Path object

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, dictionary, path

I'm using the `pathlib Path` module to store the paths of a couple of my programs. The problem is, when I go to use this variable, I end up with an error because the `\\` gets turned into a `\` which the system in interpreting as a special character. My understanding was that depending on the OS, the `Path` module would handle this accordingly. (I'm using Windows)

Here is a recreation of my code:

```
from pathlib import Path

def get_dictionary():
    path1 = Path("C:\\Programs\\program1")
    path2 = Path("C:\\Programs\\program2")
    path3 = Path("C:\\Programs\\program3")
    path4 = Path("C:\\Programs\\program4")

    info = {
        "program1" : str(path1),
        "program2" : str(path2),
        "program3" : str(path3),
        "program4" : str(path4)
    }

    return info

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theInfo = get_dictionary()
    print(theInfo['program1'])
    print(theInfo['program2'])
    print(theInfo['program3'])
    print(theInfo['program4'])

    print(theInfo)
```

And the console output is the following:

```
C:\Programs\program1
C:\Programs\program2
C:\Programs\program3
C:\Programs\program4
{'program1': 'C:\\Programs\\program1', 'program2': 'C:\\Programs\\program2', 'program3': 
'C:\\Programs\\program3', 'program4': 'C:\\Programs\\program4'}
```

So my question is: Say I want to use `theInfo['program1']`. I get `C:\Programs\program1` but I need to get `C:\\Programs\\program1`. How can I go about doing this? Thank you for any help!

Edit: The values I get from the dictionary are placed in a string that ends up being a line in a Tcl file. For instance I have a function where I write:

```
f"puts {theInfo['program1']}"
```

where I expect:

```
puts C:\\Programs\\program1
```

but I get:

```
puts C:\Programs\program1
```

With other characters, this interprets as a tab, newline, ect...

Comment: If you want to use the path string in a function like "open" you need the variant with one backslash. The double backslash is a string **repr**esentation suitable to use as string literal in Python code.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you for your response, I edited the post to show the exact use case

Comment: If you're going to embed these strings in Tcl code, you need to perform Tcl escaping. Pathlib has no idea about Tcl.

Comment: Imagine if some attacker managed to get your code to create a file named `[exec something terrible]`. That would end up in your Tcl code verbatim, and Tcl would treat that as Tcl code to execute, even though no backslashes are involved and none of the characters are treated specially in a Python string literal.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for the input, that's a good way to look at this. I'm newer to Tcl scripting so I wasn't sure about that. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phenomenon is caused caused by `Escape character '\'`, if you really want the escaped data to be `C:\\Programs\\program1`， you can split the path then join it with `\\\\`.

```
In [4]: data = 'C:\\Programs\\program1'

In [5]: data
Out[5]: 'C:\\Programs\\program1'

In [6]: print(data)
C:\Programs\program1

In [7]: new_data = 'C:\\\\Programs\\\\program1'

In [8]: new_data
Out[8]: 'C:\\\\Programs\\\\program1'

In [9]: print(new_data)
C:\\Programs\\program1

In [21]: p = '\\\\'.join(("C:\\Programs\\program1").split('\\'))

In [22]: p
Out[22]: 'C:\\\\Programs\\\\program1'

In [23]: print(p)
C:\\Programs\\program1
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it for me, I accepted your answer but I don't have enough rep yet to upvote you